# Selenium-Python-How to submit the button only after it is enabled?

Tags: python, selenium, isenabled

I have web page, where the user needs to upload a list of documents and only after which the Submit button is enabled.

I am using python selenium for this automation. My program is able to upload the documents but is unable to click on the Submit button after it is enabled.

I tried this:
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10000).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable("(//button[@type='submit'][2]"))
        element.click()

but it is not working, as the jobs are not submitted in the front end

Comment: Do you realize that `WebDriverWait(driver, 10000)` force your script to wait for `Submit` button to be clickable for about 3 hours? :)

Comment: Also provided code line is incorrect, so it will not work anyway

Comment: Thank you yeah. But, i do not know why it is not doing the job. I tried this:     self = driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//button[@type='submit'][2]")
        if self.is_enabled():
           self.click()     it is not working eighter

Comment: Provide `html` code for target element as we have no idea about what else could be wrong with your script

Comment: <input class="btn btn-primary form-control" type="submit" ng-click="configureJobsCtrl.SubmitJob()" ng-disabled="!configureJobsCtrl.enableSubmitJob">

Answer (score 1):

Change code to be:

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[contains(@ng-click,'SubmitJob')]")))
element.click()
```

So we now are waiting for up to 100 seconds (instead of 3 hours), and we are passing a tuple argument `(By.XPATH, "//input[contains(@ng-click,'SubmitJob')]")` to `EC.element_to_be_clickable`, which is what it expects.

Cannot comment on the correctness of the xpath though, but please check it as well.

**Edit**: changed the xpath based on comment. There are many ways to express that xpath. I would prefer `ng-click` over `class` attribute, since classes  may change; action, however, will likely stay the same. But if you choose using classes, I still suggest going with something like

```
//input[contains(@class,'btn') and contains(@class,'form-control')]
```

because you never know if the order of classes will change.

Comment: thank you. this is the html for the button: 
 
<input class="btn btn-primary form-control" type="submit" ng-click="configureJobsCtrl.SubmitJob()" ng-disabled="!configureJobsCtrl.enableSubmitJob">